# Apache log analyzer which manages time spent to serve the request

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, analytics

I need to monitor performance in my web server (there's an application server in the back) and create reports for senior management.

I've enabled `%T/%D` in my Apache logs and I would like to know if there's an Apache log analyzer or some other tool which parses these values and manages them showing charts or reports.

I am looking mostly for an integrated solution and not in the line of awk+gnuplot scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Would this do anything good? [apache-response-time](http://code.google.com/p/apache-response-time/)

> apache-response-time is a performance analysis tool for the apache web
>   server. It's primary focus is on script response time.
>
> One approach to improving web site performance is for a different
>   developer to improve one of the slowest scripts everyday.
>   apache-response-time is ideally suited for producing daily reports for
>   this purpose. It will help you find long running, frequently accessed
>   and large apache scripts.

Comment: It is a start :). It's not flexible about log format accepted, but hopefully I could modify the script (I can't change Apache directive)

Answer (score 1):

> I need to monitor performance in my web server

There's not a lot of stuff available for log analysis to measure performance - but it's been a couple of years since I looked very hard (currenlty using awk and jpgraph ;). PastMon can give lots of very useful data (but is difficult to configure - also uses packet sniffing rather than logs).

However the elephant in the room here is that time taken for a webserver to offload a response has [very little to do with page response times](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/) at the client. If you want to get a proper handle on the user experience then have a look at [Boomerang](https://github.com/yahoo/boomerang) + [Graphite](http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2011/02/15/measure-anything-measure-everything/) (this will also need a bit of work to configure).

Comment: I'm interested in performance of the application server backend (measured from web server) rather than client perception, but thank you for the pointers.